# Changes made reset back android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I make changes in android studio they go back to what it was. It doesn't matter what change I make it always goes back and I've tried to clean the project, rebuild it, restart android studio but nothing worked. Please help!

Any Help Would Be Appreciated!

Comment: Some files are generated automatically. If you are trying to change the manifest make sure it is not one of those which are generated at build time.

Comment: It might be, but I changed it first and now it won't work. So I am trying to revert the change back but it won't do that.

Comment: The other day I was editing the manifest and was losing all changes each build, then I realized I was not editing the right file, so double check the file name and path, maybe you're having the same issue than me.

Comment: Sorry guys! Nevermind my question, Thanks Dominique! I was editing the wrong file. Should I delete my question?

Comment: No it can help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling instant run:

For windws: 
**File**>>**Settings**>>**Build, Execution, Deployment**>> **Instant Run**

and uncheck all the values on right side